# Why does a Snackbar text disapear if the text is too long?

Tags: android, material-design, material-ui, snackbar

I have a requirement to add some user feedback using standard Snackbar in Android.

I have noticed that if my text is too long then the whole text string disappears. Rather than have an ellipses...

More specifically; on a Pixel 2 emulator the following string disappears:

"You're offline. Check your connection and try again." - This is gone

but if I remove the last character then it shows:

"You're offline. Check your connection and try again" - This shows

Even worse is that on a device with a smaller screen the length of the text that will show is reduced meaning on a Nexus 5 emulator for example:

"You're offline. Check your connection and try again" - This now doesn't show

but if I shorten it further:

"You're offline. Check your connection" - This shows

This feels like a bug to me.

I understand that Snackbar should be for very short text but none the less it shouldn't remove the text arbitrarily. It should at least show some text or an ellipses or go multi-line.

Has anyone else noticed this or can suggest if it's a bug or am I missing something?

Code example:

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.placeSnackBar),
        "You're offline. Check your connection and try again.",
        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        .setAction("X", View.OnClickListener { }).show()
```

I also tried:

```
val sb = Snackbar.make(this, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        .setActionTextColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"))
        .setAction("X", View.OnClickListener { })

sb.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
sb.view.findViewById<TextView>(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text)
        //.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"))
        .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
sb.view.findViewById<TextView>(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text)
        .singleLine = false
sb.view.findViewById<TextView>(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text)
        .maxLines = 2
sb.show()
```

XML for Coordinator layout which shows snackbar above floating footer layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/message_bar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/llFooter" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llFooter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_forgot_password"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
 ...
 />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
...
   />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

How it looks with full string:

[image]

and if I shorten the string by 1 character:

[image]

Comment: you should post your xml here. Maybe it's because of your xml view `placeSnackBar`.

Comment: As it works with 52 characters but not 51 on a pixel 2 emulator and even less on a smaller screen I don't think it is related but I can post it. Thanks

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc I shall eat my words you are on the money. It was the coordinator layout after all! Because I have a fixed height message bar container the bottom of the snack bar was being pushed down out of the visible area of the layout. I wish I could do an embarrassed emoji here :-) ... If you want me to mark your suggestion as correct answer then you can post it as an answer. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Cheers!! nvm, the cool thing is your issue was solved!

Answer (score 1):

Set your snackbar lines to 2 by accessing its `TextView`:

```
val message = "You're offline. Check your connection and try again.";
val sb = Snackbar.make(
    findViewById(R.id.newLinearLayout),
    "You're offline. Check your connection and try again.",
    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
    .setAction("X") {}
val view = sb.view
val textView = view.findViewById<View>(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
textView.maxLines = 2
sb.show()
```

Comment: I tried this and also singleLine = false and no joy :-(

Comment: @Paul you must be doing something wrong because it works as expected. But check this: even if you see no text does it look to you that its height is long enough to hold 2 lines?

Comment: I have tried that exact code and same issue. I even pasted your code directly just in case and still get the exact same result. Thanks, Paul.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions I found the issue you it was related to my coordinator layout see answer in question comments above with KingfisherPhuoc. Paul.